# What status code should a client assume if an HTTP response has a payload but no status code?

Tags: http

I was playing around my redis server and tried to hit with the browser. Redis detected it as a Cross Protocol Scripting attack and returned an error in the response's payload. However, when I checked the window's console, it turned out that the request was returned without a status code. So, in such cases what status code should a client assume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a response without a status code. Every HTTP response has one, and if you didn't get one it means:

- You weren't talking to a HTTP server.
- The HTTP server did something it shouldn't.

In each case I would expect your HTTP client to throw some kind of exception but not return a Http Response object.

Comment: Understood. Redis doesn't instantiate an HTTP server.